# How to protect your api from a compromised client

Tags: reactjs, react-native, server, stripe-payments, backend

I've built a backend Stripe server to handle payments for my react native and react app.

Something I'm concerned about is what happens when someone gets accessed to the decompiled client source code.

Is there a way I can ensure that only authorised clients can make api calls?

Comment: You should never use your Secret Key (sk_*****) in a distributed app. Only use your Publishable Key (pk_*****) and then make any secret key calls on the server side.

Comment: Yeah that is what we are doing at the moment.
The calls to the server is like this 
```
axios.post("/myserverUrl/createCharge", {
amount : 1000 ... }, headers)
```
How can I protect this from being used abused by compromised clients

Comment: "How do I secure an API" is a very broad question. Specifically to Stripe's libraries, you would pass the Token/PaymentMethod to your backend and then use it with your secret key.